# How to install laravel 4 application in a subdirectory of add-on domain (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, laravel

I have a wordpress website as an add-on domain on my shared hosting (LAMP). Now I want to install a laravel 4 application inside a sub-directory of the wordpress mapped directory,  which is already a sub-directry of public_html folder.

So consider `mywebsite.com` is my add-on domain which is mapped to `wpdir` inside `public_html`. I want to install laravel 4 application in a directory inside `wpdir`, say for example, `laravel`. Now my problem is following, considering pretty url is enabled in wordpress –

1. WordPress will completely take over any requests for `laravel` sub-directory.
2. How to match `laravel/public` request to `laravel` , so that I can access my laravel application via `mywebsite.com/laravel` instead of `mywebsite.com/laravel/public`.

Thanks in advance for all your help and effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for starters I would install laravel to a directory outside your **public_html** (call it laravel)

```
root
  |
   ---public_html
  |
   ---laravel
```

Then I would create a sym-link in your **wpdir** pointing to the **public** directory in your **laravel** directory.

folowing the patter:

```
ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink
```

You could do

```
ln -s /laravel/public /public_html/wpdir/laravel
```

Then the probably the best bet would be to create a rule in your **.htaccess** file to circumvent wordpress' pretty urls

something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^laravel($|/) - [L]
```

This link might help with the rewrite rule:

http://geronimo89.dk/2011/03/19/making-exceptions-for-wordpress-url-rewriting/

Comment: thanks for your reply. It will be better if you can explain sym-link by an example with your directory example above.